# Regular expression to make sure of the word GO

Tags: c#, regex

I'm reading all lines in a text file. How do I make sure in a regular expression that the word `GO` is the only word on the line?

```
stringsIgnore = "GO ALGORITHM";
stringsCorrect = "GO";
Regex.Match("GO", "GO");
```

Comment: What do you need a regex for? Why not `if (line == "GO")` or some such?

Comment: why would you want a Regex for that?

Comment: He probably wants to allow strings with the word GO and whitespaces and punctuation marks

Comment: @TimPietzcker - Perhaps he wants to make a Rube Goldberg machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^GO$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match match = regex.Match(text);
while (match.Success) 
{
    // Logic
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Anchor the regex to say it is for the whole line:

```
^GO$
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't need to use a Regex...

```
var line = streamReader.ReadLine();
if( line == "GO" )
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex.Match([your input string],"\bGO\b")